# ASP.NET MVC model binding - nested properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public GridSortOptions SortOptions { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class GridSortOptions
{
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public SortDirection Direction { get; set; }
}
```

And a http request: `?Column=LastName&Direction=Descending`

That request will not work, i need to update it as follow: `?SortOptions.Column=LastName&SortOptions.Direction=Descending`

Is it possible to teach ASP.NET to understand the original request without changing the model?

PS. I know that I could create a custom binder but I feel that there is a much simple way exist...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your view look like, and are you using MVC contrib?

Answer (score 0):

I have mine structured slightly differently, as I came across the same problem (in MVC1 and still have it now - mvc4) . I have often found that having nested models tend to cause headaches and unnecessary complexity, so I try to flatten my view models as much as possible, just to simplify things, so don't have to write custom model binders, saves a lot of time and code.

My action typically looks method looks like this

```
//...snip
public ActionResult List(int? page, GridSortOptions sortOptions, string keyword) {
        var model = new UserGridViewModel();
        IQueryable<User> users = new UserRepository(Session).List();
        if (sortOptions.Column != null) {
            users = users.OrderBy(sortOptions.Column, sortOptions.Direction);
        }

        if (keyword != null) {
            users = users.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(keyword))
        }

        model.SortOptions = sortOptions;

        //using MvcContrib.Pagination.PaginationHelper here
        model.Results = users.AsPagination(page ?? 1, 20);
        return View(model);
}
//.....
```

My view logic is simply:

```
@using MvcContrib.UI.Grid
@using MvcContrib.UI.Pager
@model UsersGridViewModel

@Html.Grid(Model.Results).Columns(cols => {
                              cols.For(col => col.Id).Sortable(true);
                              cols.For(col => col.Name).Sortable(true);
                               //...etc
                             }).Sort(Model.SortOptions)
```

My grid view models are normally like this:

```
public class UserGridViewModel
{
    public IPagination<User> Results { get; set; }
    public GridSortOptions SortOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That how it works now. But I have many parameters on my action, like term, different filters, page and some state for the grid. It would be better to wrap it inside an object.

Comment: I have simplified my example here, I my projects , I have an interface for grid models, and a set of generic abstract base classes with common methods that "automatically" handle some of the common logic for grid views, however maybe you models are a bit more complex. Can you give me an example or you typical action?